# Architecture layer diagram validation not working in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to setup a simple architecture layer diagram to validate that we don't break our layering rules by using namespaces/dll's from incorrect layers.

I setup a simple solution that has a console app, and 4 dll's (all using .Net Core).  The console app calls into Dll1, Dll1 calls into Dll2, Dll2 calls into Dll3, etc.  Then I setup a layer diagram to enforce this layering and try to have the console app call into Dll 4 and expected to get an error; however, I don't.

If I change this to use a windows form app (instead of the .net core console app) and change all the dll's to be .net standard, then I do get the error enforcing the layer diagram.

I've tried adding the Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers NuGet package to the .net core console app, but that still doesn't work.  Is this a problem in .Net Core?  Or something I'm missing?

Comment: Tried doing another test with all .net core but used an MVC app instead of a console app.  I get the following error when building the solution (and the dependency layer diagram doesn't go instead the MVC app).   CSC : warning DV2001: The project does not reference any Dependency Validation diagrams or referenced diagrams are not valid. Dependency validation will not be performed.

Answer (score 4):

I can't take the credit for this answer, however I found this solution buried in GitHub. 
 The manual workaround is listed [>here in github<](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/856#issuecomment-398098563).  It got the Dependency Validation Diagram working fine for me in dotnet core.

> Dependency validation works fine for old-style MSBuild projects, and
>   the only reason it appears not to work for new-style MSBuild projects
>   is that dependency validation designer doesn't add the NuGet package
>   and the link to the model file because it doesn't recognise the
>   new-style projects as being C#/VB projects.
>
> This is purely an IDE issue - the dependency validation designer
>   doesn't know the GUIDs for the new-style C# and VB project types, so
>   it doesn't show a gold bar to fix up the project files. The underlying
>   validation mechanism is just using Roslyn analyzers and linked files,
>   both of which are fully supported in MSBuild15.
>
> **Manual workaround:** 
>   For each .Net Standard/Core project that you want
>   to validate:
>
> Add a reference to the Microsoft.Dependency.Validation.Analyzer NuGet
>   package Add the layer diagram as a linked file with the ItemGroup type
>   of AdditionalFiles
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
>     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
>   </PropertyGroup>
>
>   <!-- Add support for Layer validation -->
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers" Version="0.9.0" />
>
>     <!-- Include the layer model as an additional file that will be passed to the analyzer />
>     <AdditionalFiles Include="..\LayerTest1\DependencyValidation1.layerdiagram">
>       <Link>DependencyValidation1.layerdiagram</Link>
>       <Visible>False</Visible>
>     </AdditionalFiles>
>   </ItemGroup>
>
> </Project>
> ```
>
> **Background**
>
> The dependency validation engine was re-written
>   in VS2017 to use Roslyn analyzers, rather than a separate command line
>   executable. One implication of this is that every code project being
>   validated now needs to have a reference to the NuGet package
>   containing the analyzers, and also a pointer to the layer model file.
>   This needs to be added as a linked file so there is only one copy of
>   the model that is shared between all projects, and it needs to belong
>   to the AdditionalFiles ItemGroup, as this is the mechanism used by
>   Roslyn to pass additional configuration to analyzers.
>
> (Aside: another implication is that the only way to reliably see all
>   dependency validation errors in the IDE is to rebuild the solution.
>   Otherwise, VS will try not build projects that haven't changed, so the
>   Roslyn analyzers won't be called -> no validation errors produced).
>
> **"Projects need to be updated" gold bar**
>
> If a solution contains a
>   dependency validation diagram, the dependency validation designer in
>   the Visual Studio IDE will scan the solution for project types it
>   recognises as containing C# or VB code, and check that those projects
>   contain the analyzer NuGet reference and the link to the model file.
>   If they don't then the "[o]ne or more projects needs to be updated to
>   perform dependency validation" gold bar will be shown.
>
> However, the dependency validation designer only knows about the
>   old-style C# and VB project types (GUIDs
>   FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC and
>   F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F respectively). It doesn't know
>   about the new-style C# and VB projects
>   (9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556 and
>   778DAE3C-4631-46EA-AA77-85C1314464D9) because they were released after
>   VS2017 RTM.

Comment: Take a look also to https://thuru.net/2018/07/02/dependency-validation-diagrams-does-not-work-in-asp-net-core-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer that David gave you can also add an `Directory.Build.props` to the solution root folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- Add support for Layer validation -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DependencyValidation.Analyzers" Version="0.10.0" />

    <!-- Include the layer model as an additional file that will be passed to the analyzer /> -->
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Architecture\DependencyValidation.layerdiagram">
      <Link>DependencyValidation1.layerdiagram</Link>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </AdditionalFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This will add the dependency validation analyzer and diagram to all projects in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/layer-diagrams-reference?view=vs-2017 has the note:

> Dependency diagrams are not supported for .NET Core projects in Visual
>   Studio 2017.